# PHP date validation and comparison

Tags: php, validation, date

```
$datesql='UPDATE products set past=1 where " '.$row['valid_date'].' " > CURDATE()';
mysql_query($datesql);
```

What's wrong with the above query? It has set the 'past' to 1 without checking the condition. How can I improve this code?

Comment: what is $row['valid_date']? . column name or value?. It should be column name

Comment: a array variable from the table 'products' with which i want to compare the current date.

Comment: Yeah,It is a column name

Comment: The biggest issue with that code, is that it's using the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: _"What's wrong with..."_ without any information about _what happens when you try it_ doesn't help us help you. So tell us, what happens? Any error message? Have you checked your error log? Do you have display errors turned on in PHP? What you _you_ done to debug your code?

Comment: Display errors are on.....and there are no errors showing.Ive tried all the codes given to me in various comments,and still the is no change in my result. The result im expecting is "for all valid_date > CURDATE() the past must be 1 else it must be 0" can you help me with some code? @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information. What kind of data is storing $row['valid_date'] ? Timestamp?

Anyway, not sure what you want to get, but usually if the value is > than CURDATE(), it would be past=0.

Then the correct way would be:

```
'UPDATE products set past=1 where " '.$row['valid_date'].' " < CURDATE()';
```

I mean, if the date is more than current one, it is in the future, so conventionally would be past=0, otherwise would be in the past, so past=1

But, as are conventions, may be you are using adifferent one.

One more very important off topic note: mysql_query() was removed in PHP 7

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment and should be written as one.

Comment: May be you are right , my hypothetical answer (due to lack of information) is : you are doing it the other way around. (just added it as answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$var1=$row["valid_date"];
$datesql="UPDATE `products` set `past`=1 where $var1 > CURDATE()";          
$res=mysql_query($datesql);
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$datesql="UPDATE products set past=1 where ".$row['valid_date']." > CURDATE()";
mysql_query($datesql);
```

I assume this should work iff $row['valid_date'] is name of column in your table.

If not once, echo your query and then try to execute on your mysql browser.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is datetime or date, below code may help you

```
 $datesql='UPDATE products set past=1 where '.$row['valid_date'].' > CURDATE()';
```